# How to add a new translation to the backend?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

So far I've translated the language files in the /modules/*/lang/et/ folders.
5 files total.

There are more changes required to enable the new translation. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/octobercms/october/pull/2648/files which added a Lithuanian translation.

Comment: modules/system/lang/lt/lang.php includes the names of all the other locales. Therefore this file should be updated for all the languages?

Comment: The natural name for the language should be present in the default system language file (i.e. en/lang.php) if possible, it shouldn't be translated though.

Comment: But the backend preferences model uses the translation from the active locale: `Lang::get('system::lang.locale.et')`
Doesn't that require the translation to be present in translation files for all the languages?

Comment: Same goes for the `php artisan october:util compile lang` command

Comment: dragontree, the translations trickle down. If your currently selected language doesn't have a value for the requested translation string, it looks at the default language (which is usually still set to English) to get the value for that string.

Comment: `php artisan october:util compile lang` is used to compile JS translations, as used by `modules/system/lang/en/client.php`

Comment: aah, nice. I'll make the PR soon

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly duplicate lang folder in the modules/backend and modules/system folders them from the language files.
2. Rename the folder name according to the iso standard. (Example: Like en, ru, tr, az and etc.)
3. Then add the information about the language you want to add to the modules / backend / models / Preference.php file.

The new language you created will appear in the CMS \ back-end preferences section.
[image: Screenshot new language]